# SQL update table , case when, select distinct

Tags: sql, case, distinct

I have 2 tables as below

Table 1: `r_report8`

| work_order_no | report8a | report_item7 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EGR220511003493 | 56 | 1 |

Table2 : `rjob_header`

| work_order_no | report_item7 |
| --- | --- |
| EGR220511003493 | 1 |

I already set a triggers on both table

Table 1: `r_report8`

```
DECLARE @workorderno nvarchar(15),@report_item7 int

SELECT @workorderno = WORK_ORDER_NO 
FROM inserted

IF (UPDATE(REPORT8A)) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE R_REPORT8 
    SET REPORT_ITEM7 = (CASE WHEN (REPORT8A<>'') THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)
    WHERE @workorderno = WORK_ORDER_NO 
END
```

Table 2: `rjob_header`

```
DECLARE @workorderno nvarchar(15), @report_item7 int

SELECT @workorderno = WORK_ORDER_NO 
FROM inserted

UPDATE RJOB_HEADER 
SET REPORT_ITEM7 = (CASE 
                       WHEN (SELECT DISTINCT b.report_item7 
                             FROM rjob_header a 
                             INNER JOIN r_report8 b ON b.work_order_no = a.work_order_no 
                             WHERE a.work_order_no = @workorderno) IS NOT NULL 
                           THEN '1' 
                           ELSE '0' 
                    END)
    WHERE @workorderno = WORK_ORDER_NO 
END
```

2 tables will update by our system form in same time.

When (Table1) dbo.r_report8.report8a updated. The column report_item7 will change be '1' and (Table2) dbo.rjob_header.report_item7 also be '1'

But If I delete the record in (Table1) dbo.r_report8, The column report_item7 still be '1'.

How can I do it when the record deleted from (Table1) dbo.r_report8,(Table2) dbo.rjob_header.report_item7 change back to '0' or null?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a delete trigger as below:

Delete Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_r_report8_after_delete
ON dbo.r_report8
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @workorderno nvarchar(15)

    SELECT @workorderno = WORK_ORDER_NO 
    FROM deleted

    -- Check if any related records exist in r_report8
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM r_report8 WHERE work_order_no = @workorderno)
    BEGIN
        -- Update rjob_header to set report_item7 to 0 
        UPDATE rjob_header
        SET report_item7 = 0 
        WHERE work_order_no = @workorderno
    END
END
```

Select from tables before deletion:

```
select * from r_report8;
select * from rjob_header;
```

| work_order_no | report8a | report_item7 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EGR220511003493 | 56 | 1 |

| work_order_no | report_item7 |
| --- | --- |
| EGR220511003493 | 1 |

Delete from r_report8:

```
delete r_report8
```

Select from the tables after deletion:

```
select * from r_report8;
select * from rjob_header;
```

| work_order_no | report8a | report_item7 |
| --- | --- | --- |

| work_order_no | report_item7 |
| --- | --- |
| EGR220511003493 | 0 |

*** report_item7 is set to 0 in rjob_header table for work_order_no EGR220511003493

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TMvcPsJn)

Comment: I had found a error message as bleow : Maximun stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit32)

Comment: Which operation you were performing while got this error?

Comment: i don't know , when I run it on SQL, the message appears

Comment: After I delete the record in dbo.r_report8, the message appears. "Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit32)"

Comment: Delete trigger on r_report8 and update trigger on rjob_header might having cascading effect. Please try it after removing the updte trigger to find out  the issue.

Comment: How can I use same triggers when IF exists then update set reportitem7 = 1